# How .{n} and ?<option>: works in `Regexp` on Ruby 1.9.3 environment

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.9.3

I was trying to understand how `.{n}`  and `?<option>:` works in `Regexp` on Ruby 1.9.3 environment. But couldn't understand how the below code produce the output:

```
irb(main):001:0> %W{fin\n fi\n\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.{2}(?m:.)\Z/
=> ["fin\n", "fin\r\n", "find"]
irb(main):002:0> %W{fin\n fi\n\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.{1}(?m:.)\Z/
=> ["fin\n", "fi\n\n"]
irb(main):003:0> %W{fin\n fi\n\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.{1}(?m:.)\Z/
=> []
irb(main):010:0> %W{fin\n fi\n\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.(?m:.)\Z/
=> ["fin\n", "fi\n\n"]
irb(main):011:0> %W{fin\n fi\n\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.(m:.)\Z/
=> []
irb(main):012:0> %W{fin\n fi\n\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.(?m:.)\z/
=> []
```

Can anyone help me to understand how the above code worked to generate the mentioned output in `IRB` terminal?

Thanks,

---

***As per @Kevin last paragraph*** I tried below and found expected and desirable output :

```
irb(main):014:0> %W{fin fi\n\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.(?m:.)\z/
=> ["fin"]
irb(main):015:0> %W{fin fi\n\n \n\n fin\r find}.grep /f.(?m:.)\z/
=> ["fin"]
irb(main):016:0> %W{fin fi\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.(?m:.)\z/
=> ["fin", "fi\n"]
irb(main):017:0> %W{fin fi\n \n\n fr\n find}.grep /f.(?m:.)\z/
=> ["fin", "fi\n", "fr\n"]
irb(main):018:0>
```

Thank you very much ***@Kevin*** . You helped me to understand the whole concept!

Comment: `m` option in Ruby is actually DOTALL option, which allow `.` to match `\n`. (Not sure why Ruby differs on this point, though).

Comment: Don't you mean `.{n}` instead of `.(n)` (with `n` any number)?

Comment: @Tinctorius Sorry! I corrected now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{n}` means "repeat the previous atom `n` times". In regular expressions, an atom is a self-contained unit. So a single character is an atom. So is a dot. A group is an atom as well (that contains other atoms), as is a character class. So `.{n}` means "match `n` characters" (because `.` means "match any character").

Note that `{n}` is not like a backreference, in that it doesn't have to match the same text on each repetition. `.{5}` behaves exactly like `.....`.

This construct is also more powerful. It can take two numbers, and it matches a repetition count for that whole range. So `.{3,5}` means "match 3 to 5 characters". And `.{3,}` means "match 3 or more characters". `?` can be replaced with `{0,1}`, `*` with `{0,}`, and `+` with `{1,}` if you so desired.

---

`?<option:` isn't actually a thing. It's `(?<option>:<pattern>)`, and this turns on all the flags listed in `<option>` for the duration of `<pattern>`. It's like a group, except it doesn't actually create a back reference. So the expression `(?m:.)` means "match one character as if the flag `m` was turned on". Given the behavior of `m` as "match \n" as nhahtdh said in the comments, the expression `.(?m:.).` means "match any character besides newline, followed by any character, followed by any character besides newline".

This construct has two benefits. First, it allows you to only have a flag apply to part of a pattern, which can be occasionally useful. And second, if you wrap your entire pattern in this construct, then you have control over the flags that apply to your regular expression regardless of where the expression is used. This is useful when you're providing the regex as a user and don't have control over the source of the program.

---

Let's take a look at the examples you gave:

```
> %W{fin\n fi\n\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.{2}(?m:.)\Z/
=> ["fin\n", "fin\r\n", "find"]
```

Your pattern `/f.{2}(?m:.)\Z/` means "match f, followed by 2 of any character (but newline), followed by any character, and anchor to the end of the string or just before a newline".

So in each of the 3 matches, `fin` matches the `f.{2}`. `(?m:.)` matches `\n` in the first, `\r` in the second, and `d` in the third. And `\Z` matches the end of the string in the first, just before a newline in the second, and the end of the string in the third.

`fi\n\n` doesn't match because the first `\n` here can't be matched by the `.` from `.{2}` without the `m` flag.

```
> %W{fin\n fi\n\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.{1}(?m:.)\Z/
=> ["fin\n", "fi\n\n"]
```

Here `fi` matches `f.{1}` in both cases. `(?m:.)` matches `n` and `\n`, and `\Z` matches before the newline in both cases.

`fin\r\n` doesn't match because `\Z` will only match before the final newline in the string, not before a CRLF pair. And `find` doesn't match because there's nothing to match the `d`.

```
> %W{fin\n fi\n\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.{1}(?m:.)\Z/
=> []
```

I think you have a copy & paste error here. This is identical to the previous pattern and matches as that does.

```
> %W{fin\n fi\n\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.(?m:.)\Z/
=> ["fin\n", "fi\n\n"]
```

This is also identical to the previous pattern. `.` and `.{1}` are the same thing. In fact, `{1}` can always be stripped from any regular expression without changing anything.

```
> %W{fin\n fi\n\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.(m:.)\Z/
=> []
```

You dropped the `?` in this pattern, changing the meaning of `(m:.)`. This no longer changes options. Now it's just a capturing group that matches the pattern `m:.`, which of course doesn't occur in your input.

```
> %W{fin\n fi\n\n \n\n fin\r\n find}.grep /f.(?m:.)\z/
=> []
```

You changed `\Z` to `\z` here. The difference between those two is `\Z` may match before a trailing newline, but `\z` must only match the end of the string. Without being able to match before the trailing newline, none of your inputs here match. But, for example, if you had `fin` (without the newline) or `fi\n` (without the second newline) it would work.

Comment: As a newbie, I can't troubleshoot my description mentioned codes. But I got the theory from your post. So could you explain it by my code? Hope that would clear my concept in all directions. Please?

Comment: @DoLoveSky: I just edited my post to explain each one of your given examples.

Comment: Yes,I am too happy to see your post, and also going through the theory you posted and the code's also! Thanks you very much! Please be my teacher, :) i am newbie to this platform,eager to learn it from the root! hope I can do , if you guys help! At-last `+1` to you to take care of my post!

Comment: @DoLoveSky: The best way to get familiar with regular expressions is to just keep using them. And every time you see one, make sure you understand precisely what it's doing, even if that means printing out the regexp syntax and taping it next to your monitor. Just be aware that there's a multitude of different regexp engines each with their own different behaviors, so maybe just stick to regexps found in ruby code for the time being.

Comment: Yes,I will follow your instructions, and I have many more to test now on `IRB`. Keep trying to understand them!

Comment: I am bit confused with `find` not coming in the second output but came in the first. Just confused what helped find to come in first but not to the second. You explained all but this is my failure i am not able to catch the point!

Comment: @DoLoveSky: The first pattern matches 4 characters before the end of the string (or trailing newline). The second pattern only matches 3 characters. "find" has 4 characters in it, so it can't match the 3-character pattern.

Comment: @DoLoveSky: Note of course that if you remove the `\Z` then "find" will match because the pattern is no longer anchored. Similarly if you replaced the `f` with a `.` then "find" would match because the pattern would match the "ind". But with the initial `f` and the `\Z` anchor, "find" just doesn't work.

Comment: I am now fully confident on the post with all your logic get in my nerve :) see my answer, what you instructed me too do, I tried and succeeded.